# moodle:summary image not display in custom page

Tags: php, html, mysql, moodle

when I get summary image in my custom page it will not display and print the name of image with small icon image like that

```
 echo format_text($course->summary);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fBYq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the file URLs. Also, you can use the renderer function to rewrite the file URLs

```
global $CFG;
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/renderer.php');
$renderer = new coursecat_helper();
$summary = $renderer->get_course_formatted_summary($course);
return $summary;
```

Or use the below method to rewrite the file in summary.

```
$context = context_course::instance($course->id);
$summary = file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls($course->summary, 'pluginfile.php',
            $context->id, 'course', 'summary', null);
```